# How to return matched regex in R gsub

Tags: regex, r

This is pretty basic, but I can't seem to find how to return the already-matched expression in regexes in R.

For example, suppose I wanted to add a period after an initial, for example in changing `"Joe J Smith"` to `"Joe J. Smith"`.

My approach is to use `gsub("(?<=\\s|^)[A-Z](?=\\S|$)","\\1.",string,perl=T)`. (I'm no expert on regex, but I thought `\\1` or `$1` would return the matched expression, i.e. `"J"` for the string given.

For nought, though, as this returns: `"Joe . Smith"`

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't find any examples trying to do something similar in R, which has its own brand of base regex.

Comment: Try `sub(' ([A-Z]) ', ' \\1. ', v1)` where `v1 <- "Joe J Smith"`  But I haven't tested with other cases.  If you have other patterns, you should include that in the example

Comment: now way to do this in with `perl=T`? I'm trying to use something similar to capitalize any letter immediately after a hyphen (e.g. `"Joe Jones-smith"`->`"Joe Jones-Smith"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can use `"\\b"` to refer to word boundaries:

```
> gsub("\\b([A-Z])\\b", "\\1.", "Joe J Smith")
[1] "Joe J. Smith"
```

Regarding capitalizing the letter after a hyphen:

```
> gsub("(-.)", "\\U\\1", "Joe Jones-smith", perl = TRUE)
[1] "Joe Jones-Smith"
```

Comment: `\\b` is basically a stand-in for the look-ahead and look-behind I was using in my attempt? Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Like akrun indicated, you need to parenthetise the capital letter to form a group.  This is what `?regex` says:

```
     The backreference '\N', where 'N = 1 ... 9', matches the substring
     previously matched by the Nth parenthesized subexpression of the
     regular expression.  (This is an extension for extended regular
     expressions: POSIX defines them only for basic ones.)
```

Adding the parens gives this example:

```
R>x
[1] "joe J smith"
R>gsub("(?<=\\s|^)([A-Z])(?=\\s|$)","\\1.",x,perl=TRUE)
[1] "joe J. smith"
```

Comment: I blew right by the first sentence there when poking around in the docs. thank you.